# Loose focus after second click on button

Tags: css, sass

I've got the following styling:

```
.btn-dropdown {
  height: 30px;
  background: transparent;
  border: solid 1.4px #ffffff;
  font-size: 10px;
  color: white;
  min-width: 0;
  max-width: fit-content;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 6px;

  &:hover {
    background: white;
    color: $blue;
  }

  &:active,
  &:focus {
    background: white;
    color: $blue;
    box-shadow: none;
    outline:none;  
    &::after {
      background: transparent;
    }
  }
}
```

html

```
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-dropdown dropdown-toggle">
                   abcd          
   <i class="far fa-chevron-down"></i>
    </button>
```

I want to achieve the following behaviour:

1) After the button is clicked a second time, it shall loose it's focus.

Is it possible with pure SCSS/CSS? I googled a bit and found some unsatisfying solutions like pointer-events: none ..

Thanks in advance

Comment: Post the HTML too.

Comment: you can't count clicks with css only so you would most likely need a js solution

Comment: @RazvanZamfir edited the main post with html

Comment: So "loose it's focus" in practice, means loose background color, right?

Comment: @RazvanZamfir correct! it shall be back to transparent again.

Comment: Do you need a CSS/SASS only solution?

Comment: @RazvanZamfir yeah, if possible. It's because the design shall be the same for all projects in our company, and our designs are from an external one. I have the permission to merge into their style repository.

Comment: Do you have the ability to change HTML?

Comment: @iddo yes, I can freely edit the HTML

Answer (score 1):

I have a CSS and JavaScript (NO jQuery) solution:

```js
function isHidden(el) {
  var style = window.getComputedStyle(el);
  return (style.display === 'none')
}

const list = document.getElementById('drop');
const btn = document.getElementById('btn');

btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (isHidden(list) == true) {
    btn.classList.add("active");
    list.style.display = 'flex';
  } else {
    btn.classList.remove("active");
    list.style.display = 'none'
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #121212;
}

.list-group {
  display: none;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.list-group.active {
  display: flex;
}

.list-group-item {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding: 0.75rem 1.25rem;
  margin-bottom: -1px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125);
}

.btn-dropdown {
  height: 30px;
  background: transparent;
  border: solid 1.4px #ffffff;
  font-size: 10px;
  color: white;
  min-width: 0;
  max-width: fit-content;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 6px;
}

.btn-dropdown:hover {
  background: white;
  color: #069;
}

.btn-dropdown.active {
  background: white;
  color: #069;
  box-shadow: none;
  outline: none;
}

.btn-dropdown.active::after {
  background: transparent;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" id="btn" class="btn btn-dropdown dropdown-toggle">Button          
       <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
</button>

<ul class="list-group" id="drop">
  <li class="list-group-item">Cras justo odio</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Morbi leo risus</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Porta ac consectetur ac</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Vestibulum at eros</li>
</ul>
```

The button still has a white background while you're hovering because of the hover state:

```
.btn-dropdown:hover {
  background: white;
  color: #069;
}
```

If you "unhover" it becomes transparent.

The SASS version can be seen in **[this](https://jsfiddle.net/3kqtgxew/)** jsFiddle.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is based on a (hidden) checkbox hack.

```css
body {
  background: #121212;
}

/* Magic starts here */
#toggle-checkbox {
  display: none;
}

#toggle-checkbox:checked ~ .list-group {
  display: flex;
}
/* Magic ends here */

.list-group {
  display: none;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.list-group-item {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding: 0.75rem 1.25rem;
  margin-bottom: -1px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125);
}

.btn-dropdown {
  background: transparent;
  border: solid 1px #fff;
  font-size: 10px;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.btn-dropdown > label {
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.btn-dropdown:hover {
  background: #fff;
  color: #069;
}

.btn-dropdown.active {
  background: #fff;
  color: #069;
  box-shadow: none;
  outline: none;
}

.btn-dropdown.active::after {
  background: transparent;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="toggle-checkbox" />

<button type="button" id="btn" class="btn btn-dropdown dropdown-toggle"><label for="toggle-checkbox">Click me</label>
</button>

<ul class="list-group" id="drop">
  <li class="list-group-item">Cras justo odio</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Morbi leo risus</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Porta ac consectetur ac</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Vestibulum at eros</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: CSS only: great solution.